# Root Site Facet not returned on sites/search call

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

When making a call to the Microsoft Graph `/sites?search` endpoint, a root site facet is not returned.

Here is an example of the search:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=fake Archive
```

It returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [{
        "createdDateTime": "2017-11-04T18:52:44Z",
        "id": "fakeau.sharepoint.com,0f736b6a-d7fa-498d-b13f-72af82d58b49,7c055ac7-0d31-4341-8158-8055950f37c8",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-11-14T23:21:51Z",
        "name": "fake Archive",
        "webUrl": "https://fakeau.sharepoint.com/sites/fake Archive",
        "displayName": "fake fake Archive"
    }]
}
```

There is no root site facet. If I use the `/site` endpoint to access the site directly:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/fakeau.sharepoint.com,0f736b6a-d7fa-498d-b13f-72af82d58b49,7c055ac7-0d31-4341-8158-8055950f37c8
```

I get the response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-11-14T23:19:51.437Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "fakeau.sharepoint.com,0f736b6a-d7fa-498d-b13f-72af82d58b49,7c055ac7-0d31-4341-8158-8055950f37c8",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-23T12:23:40Z",
    "name": "fake Archive",
    "webUrl": "https://fakeau.sharepoint.com/sites/fake Archive",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "fakeau.sharepoint.com"
    },
    "displayName": "fake fake Archive"
}
```

Notice this now has a root site facet.

Is this a bug, or are there some situations in which the root site facet should not be shown in the `/sites?search` results?

Answer (score 0):

The [`sites/search` endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/site_search) only returns a small subset of a site's properties:

`id`, `name`, `description`, `createdDateTime`,`lastModifiedDateTime`, and `webUrl`.

In order to retrieve the full metadata, you'll need to make subsequent requests to the `/sites/{id}` endpoint.

Comment: does the above make sense?

Comment: Something is inconsistent then, as I see root site identifiers on other sites returned in the search: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search= { "id": "fake.sharepoint.com,fa15c98b-7fe8-46ad-8014-730726f982d0,32a3634f-7fd4-4672-821d-c4ae518ad5d1", "name": "fake.sharepoint.com", "webUrl": "fake.sharepoint.com";, "root": {}, "siteCollection": { "hostname": "fake.sharepoint.com" }, }, @Marc LaFleur